# pyqt and websocket client. listen websocket in background

Tags: python, websocket, pyqt

I have a PyQt Gui application. This application have a main window that should be open after the start.

This application should to listen the websocket.

I tried solve it so:

```
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8080/chatsocket",
                                on_message = on_message,
                                on_error = on_error,
                                on_close = on_close)
#    ws.on_open = on_open

    ws.run_forever()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But, after start application the main window was not open.

Without line "ws.run_forever()" the main window was open but application does not listen websocket.

I need listen the websocket in the "background"?
Can you help me?

PS: (Sorry for my english)

Comment: You have to run the socket in another thread.

Comment: I realize this question is fairly old, maybe, if I find some time a will still post an exhaustive answer. Until then, while using PyQt, there is no reason to resort to the websocket module as Qt Provides QWebSockets that integrate beautifully with the rest of your architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks enginefree.

I make this

```
class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.thread = ListenWebsocket()
        self.thread.start()

...


class ListenWebsocket(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListenWebsocket, self).__init__(parent)

        websocket.enableTrace(True)

        self.WS = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8080/chatsocket",
                                on_message = self.on_message,
                                on_error = self.on_error,
                                on_close = self.on_close) 

    def run(self):
        #ws.on_open = on_open

        self.WS.run_forever()


    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        print message

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print error

    def on_close(self, ws):
        print "### closed ###"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    QtGui.QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```