# PyQt and WebSockets

Tags: python, user-interface, websocket, pyqt

I'm creating a desktop application that is interfaced with using a mobile app or mobile communications ( twitter, txt )

I already have the mechanisms in place to share media ( youtube, instagram, )
with the desktop app from a mobile device.

But, I would like to add a websocket chatbox to the desktop interface. So, that users can add msgs using a webview or websocket client within the mobile app.

BUT

How do I combine websockets with pyqt?

I've found very few examples online... just looking for some insight on this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092076/pyqt-and-websocket-client-listen-websocket-in-background

Comment: Yes, I came across that example but I honestly can't follow it.

Comment: @ChristianStewart That not a dupliate as in that question the program is the `server` fora  websocket, not the client as in this `question`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to use a `QWebView`, insert that into your App and then load a HTML5 page in the WebView and use that to communicate with the server.

This way you can probably even reuse the code for the mobile client as the code for the desktop chat interface.

Comment: QWebView uses the Webkit renderering engine. I've never had a problem with any HTML5 elements that I've tried to use, but your milage may vary.