# send message to websocket server from tornado websocket client and wait for response

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, client, tornado

I am total beginner in tornado and generally websockets/networking.
What I am trying to do is to implement in desktop windowed app a websocket client, that:

- receives some random data from server, reads it, checks data and
  emits signal with it outside to some widgets
- sends data to server (with no response from server)

(up to this point I managed to this)

- sends data to server in some outside function (like in widget):

```py
def request_masks_export(self, export_dir):
        wrapped_command = {
            "clientAction": "exportMasks",
            "clientData": {
                "client": "Remote Browser is requesting to export masks files.",
                "exportDir": export_dir
            }
        }
        response = self.current_connection_manager.send_sync(wrapped_command)
        # response from send_sync here
```

...and waits until it will get response, and then proceeds within function.
I can't get my head around it to do it...

Here is my code:

```py
class ConnectionManager(QThread):
    on_data = Signal(dict)
    connection_interrupted = Signal()

    _default_url = "ws://localhost:12345/"
    _identifier = {
        "clientAction": "newClientConnected",
        "clientData": {
            "client": "connected from python app: {}".format(os.path.basename(__file__))
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, url=None, timeout=None, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ioloop = IOLoop.current()

        if url is not None:
            self.url = url
        else:
            self.url = self._default_url

        if timeout is not None:
            self.timeout = timeout
        else:
            self.timeout = 1

        self.ws_connection = None

    @gen.coroutine
    def connect_to_server(self):
        try:
            start_time = time.time()
            self.ws_connection = yield websocket_connect(self.url)
            self.ws_connection.connect_future.add_done_callback(self.connect_callback)
            print 'Elapsed time of connection: %.1f msec' % (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
            self.send(self._identifier)
        except socket.error as e:
            print e
            if e.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
                print 'Connection has been refused. Awaiting connection...'
                yield gen.sleep(self.timeout)
                self.connect_to_server()
        except Exception as e:
            print "unable to connect websocket server"
            print e

    def run(self):

        self.ioloop.spawn_callback(self.connect_to_server)

        self.ioloop.start()

    def connect_callback(self, future):
        if future.exception() is None:
            self.ws_connection = future.result()
            self._on_connection_success()
            self.read_message()
        else:
            self.on_connection_error(future.exception())

    @gen.coroutine
    def read_message(self):
        # reading here all messages, except those that are result of def send_sync
        while True:
            msg = yield self.ws_connection.read_message()
            if msg is None:
                self.on_connection_close()
                break
            self.check_data(msg)

    @gen.coroutine
    def send(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            json_object = json.dumps(data)
            res = yield self.ws_connection.write_message(json_object)
    #         from here I just send messages that don't need response

    @gen.coroutine
    def send_sync(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            json_object = json.dumps(data)
            response = yield self.ws_connection.write_message(json_object)
    #         I want to get response messege from server here to be able to return it 'somehow'

    def check_data(self, raw_msg):
        """
        Callback function when message is received from server.
        Emits signal
        :param raw_msg: unicode message received from server
        :return:
        """
        try:
            if raw_msg is None:
                raise WebSocketNoneError("raw_msg received is None!", "none data")

            try:
                raw_data_dict = json.loads(raw_msg)
            except ValueError as e:
                # handles json decode error from raw_msg(string)
                print e
                raise WebSocketMessageError("Incompatible message type!", "JSON only")

            if raw_data_dict.has_key("serverAction"):
                self.on_data.emit(raw_data_dict)
                return raw_data_dict
            else:
                raise WebSocketMessageError("Incompatible message structure!", "missing serverAction")

        except WebSocketMessageError as e:
            print e.args
            raise
        except WebSocketNoneError as e:
            print e.args
            raise

    def close_manager(self):
        """
        Method for stopping websocket, waiting for thread to finish and stop it.
        :return:
        """
        self.close_websocket()
        self.ioloop.stop()
        self.stop()

    def is_connected(self):
        if not self.ws_connection:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def stop(self):
        """
        Stop thread.
        :return:
        """
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

    def close_websocket(self):
        """
        Close websocket.
        :return:
        """
        try:
            self.ws_connection.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            pass

    def on_connection_success(self):
        print "_on_connection_success"
        pass

    def on_connection_close(self):
        print "_on_connection_close"
        self.connection_interrupted.emit()
        self.connect_to_server()
        pass
```

I am using:

```
class ConnectionManager(QThread):
```

Because it was blocking the thread that was used for rest of the app... Is this proper way to do it? Correct me if I am wrong but I wouldn't do it in `QThread` then whole app would load up to the point of iolopp.start() and wouldn't execute past that element, instead it would wait/listen for incoming messages, etc...

Also I am a bit confused about connection types in tornado. There isn't many examples of websocket connections, instead there is a lot about HTTP. Since all of this stuff is new for me, then maybe I misunderstand some things, but I thought that only initial handshake is http based in websockets and I can't use classes like `RequestHandler`, `tornado.httpclient`.

Comment: I suppose PyQT/QT already has some kind of an event-loop and even websocket libs that you should use instead of using Tornado's event-loop and networking tools (which you should leave only to your backend). [Very shallow and fast search shows, that this is quite true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092076/pyqt-and-websocket-client-listen-websocket-in-background).

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I want to use tornado and nothing else. I know that it is achievable with this, and probably fairly easy for experienced tornado users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in a yield-way, but I can see a pretty simple callback-way solution, if you are ok with that. You can achieve this through the interaction between a Tornado's event loop and QT event loop. I don't know PyQT, so I'll show some abstraction and just general idea, not working code.

```
def request_masks_export(self, export_dir):
    # ...
    IOLoop.current().add_callback(send_sync, 
                                  wrapped_command,
                                  some_func_to_call_after_request_is_finished)
```

## ...

```
@gen.coroutine
def send_sync(self, data, callback_func):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        json_object = json.dumps(data)
        response = yield self.ws_connection.write_message(json_object)
        QTEventLoop.add_callback(callback_func, response)
```